# Rows and columns alignment affecting each other [Android Studiuo]

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got a problem with TableLayout. I'm trying to place my objects in columns but every next row affects previous ones and destroys them. Here's some code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dom.zadanie2.aktywnosc2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Imie"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Płeć"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kobieta"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "Mężczyzna"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"/>

    </RadioGroup>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"/>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

When I have placed the **RatingBar**, previous rows moved out of screen. Please give me some tips, I've tried various setting but nothing works properly. I don't know what do to so rows would appear independent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any reason for, not use to Linear Layout instead of table layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:layout_weight="3"
```

to TableLayout, and in each TableRow, change

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:weightSum="1"
```

like the following

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weightSum="6"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Imie"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Płeć"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:width="0dp"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kobieta"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "Mężczyzna"

            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working good. So maybe you could tell me why `layout_gravity` doesn't work in a row? I'd like to put some **TextView** on the left of the **RatingBar** and I can't align it. It's placed on the top and there's now way to move it in other way than by `padding`

Comment: Chnged TextView's `layout_height="fill_parent"` to `wrap_content` and it's working now

Comment: I'm glad that it's working. If it's the answer enough for you, you may accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'm goint to do it but I noticed that problem is not really solved. Most rows have 2 columns but there's one where I want to put one element in a center but this row is also treated as two-column row. What's more in design mode I noticed something, it looks like there's one shared separating line for all rows. That's not what I want to achieve. I'd like to have something like 
2 columns in row 1
3 columns in row 2
1 column in row 3 etc. and I want rows to not affect each other

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Do you want RatingBar to be centralised? Then see above code, I revised my answer.

Comment: For example - first row has 2 columns and second has 2. In first row I want columns ratio to be 1:5 and in second row 5:1. It doesn't work at all. I can set second row to be 5:1 then first goes out of control.

Comment: You can change the columns' width by assigning weights to each, and sum to corresponding rows. See my revised code above.

Comment: And also, don't forget to set the widths to 0dp in case of assigning weight.

Comment: I solved it by adding `android:stretchColumns="*"` in TableLayout and then setting `layout_span` in every object in rows

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem. Can you post your solution?

Comment: You should write it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `TableLayout` and `TableRow` , Simply use `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!-- your Views -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- your Views -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- goes on like this -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd love to but it's homework and I have to use various Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to change to **Linearlayout**,

As in below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Imie"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Plec"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Kobieta" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mezczyzna" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

TableRow has by default layout_width as match_parent and layout_hieght as wrap_content, so do not specify layout_width and layout_height in TableRow tag.

Now, The main answer of your question:- In Table layout, width of each cell(View) in a column is related to other cells(views) in the same column. The width of each cell will be equal to the highest width of the cell in the same column.
In your case the rating bar is in column zero and width of the rating bar is more then other cells of same column. To overcome from this problem use layout_span="total number of columns in table layout" attribute in ranting bar view. By using this attribute your rating bar will span in all the columns.

solution of your problem is this:-

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_span="2"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"/>
</TableRow>
```